# SQL grouping function with more columns

Tags: sql, grouping, exasolution

I am trying to understand an SQL written by a colleague and I am struggling to understand how does the GROUPING() function work in this case. Why is the value of *date_level_year_quarter_month* equal to 3 and 7 in the last two rows? Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT
    t_year,
    t_quarter,
    t_month,
    GROUPING(t_year, t_quarter, t_month) date_level_year_quarter_month
FROM
    d_time
WHERE t_year IN (2016)
GROUP BY
ROLLUP(t_year, t_quarter, t_month)
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;

+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| t_year  |  t_quarter |  t_month   | date_level_year_quarter_month |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016    |      1     |      1     |               0               |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016    |      1     |      2     |               0               |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016    |      1     |      3     |               0               |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016    |      1     |            |               1               |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016    |    ...     |     ...    |              ...              |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2016    |            |            |               3               |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
|         |            |            |               7               |
+---------+------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

EDIT: 
It looks like for every dimension 'added', the value of GROUPING function is two times the value of 'previous grouping' + 1, however it is still unclear to me, how the function calculates this values in the first place.

```
SELECT 
      T_YEAR
    , T_QUARTAL
    , T_MONTH
    , T_WEEK
    , T_DATE
    , GROUPING (T_YEAR ) AS LEVEL_YEAR
    , GROUPING (T_YEAR, T_QUARTER) AS LEVEL_YEAR_QUARTAL
    , GROUPING (T_YEAR, T_QUARTER, T_MONTH) AS LEVEL_YEAR_QUARTAL_MONTH
    , GROUPING (T_YEAR, T_QUARTER, T_MONTH, T_WEEK) AS LEVEL_YEAR_QUARTAL_MONTH_WEEK
    , GROUPING (T_YEAR, T_QUARTER, T_MONTH, T_WEEK, T_DAY) AS LEVEL_YEAR_QUARTAL_MONTH_WEEK_DAY
FROM D_TIME
WHERE T_YEAR=2016 AND T_WEEK = 1
GROUP BY
ROLLUP (T_YEAR, T_QUARTER, T_MONTH, T_WEEK, T_DAY) 
ORDER BY 5,1,2,3,4;
```

[image: Grouping output:]

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Why don't you ask your colleague?

Comment: @HoneyBadger he wrote it in 2013 and is long gone from the company ;)

Comment: The ROLLUP function is a normal group by, but it also add rows for the subtotals and total (you can see them where the columns quarter/month are null). Is that's what you asking ?

Comment: @ThomasG thanks for answer. What I am trying to find out is how in this case the GROUPING(t_year, t_quarter, t_month) sums up to 7. I know it should return 1 in superaggregate rows, but how does it end up being 7 in this case?

Comment: it should be your "grand total". So the total for all months of all years

Comment: Interesting question.  I thought `GROUPING()` only took one argument.

Comment: provide your data

Comment: Hi @KavalPatel the d_time table is a dimension table including time data (such as year, quarter, month, week, day) on a daily level.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in [Exasol documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwic8eOGxenaAhWxhqYKHQV5ApkQFjABegQIABAz&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.exasol.com%2Fsupport%2Fsecure%2Fattachment%2F28846%2FEXASolution_User_Manual-5.0.0-en.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0Fxl0FaNwY40tCEgOoi6Cr).

"In case of multiple arguments the result value is a number whose binary representation is similar to

```
GROUPING(arg1), GROUPING(arg2),..., GROUPING(argn).
```

E.g. the following is true:

```
GROUPING(a,b,c) = 4xGROUPING(a) + 2xGROUPING(b) + 1xGROUPING(c)."
```